# Where to start learning the heat equation

Tags: reference-request, physics, heat-equation

So I would like to model the heat equation in python, but I don't quite know where to start. I have a grasp on the 1D model with no heat source/sink, but that is too simple for what I need. 
I am trying to model heat flow on an object being struck by a laser. So I need it to be 3D and have a heat source. If anybody could help provide some useful resources I would much appreciate it.

EDIT::
I also need to be able to account for the heat lost due to surrounding air, along with the heat gained from the laser

Comment: What would you want to learn about it? Methods to solve it numerically or analytically or something third?

Comment: I'd like to be able to solve it analytically on paper, and then write a program in python to solve it numerically for me.

Comment: The heat equation is a typical example of a problem which starts benefiting from Fourier analysis theory and is often a typical application that is used in such courses to show how to derive solutions at least for a few simple boundary shapes. So that is probably the theory I would hint to learn about. Although you should be aware that for more complicated boundaries it can be a real challenge finding analytical solutions.

Comment: If you want to use the Python programming language for numerical calculations I suppose NumPy and SciPy could be something to read up on.

Comment: $\texttt{Numerical Recipes}$ book is a nice starting point.